# d3.csv parseFloat will not parse correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js, chart.js

I am using the following code to load a simple csv file into charts.js using d3. However, no matter what I try, "order_count" will not convert to a number it remains a string. The file also automatically comes in as multiple objects instead of an object of multiple arrays. My end goal is a bar chart with bins as the x-axis and order_count on the y. Please see code and output below. Thank you!

I tried parse, I tried +d.order_count and I tried

```
var data=d3.text("DELTA_7_6_20_10.csv")
.then(text=>d3.csvParseRows(text))
.then(d=>console.log(d));

var data=d3.csv("DELTA_7_6_20_10.csv", function(d){
  return{
  bins:d.bins,
  order_count:parseFloat(d.order_count)};
},
function(d){console.log(d);
});
```

Comment: {bins: "bin_zero_two", order_count: "4"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_two_four", order_count: "2"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_four_six", order_count: "1"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_six_eight", order_count: "2"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_eight_ten", order_count: "0"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_ten_twelve", order_count: "1"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_twelve_fourteen", order_count: "0"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_fourteen_plus", order_count: "0"}

Comment: console:

{bins: "bin_zero_two", order_count: "4"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_two_four", order_count: "2"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_four_six", order_count: "1"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_six_eight", order_count: "2"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_eight_ten", order_count: "0"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_ten_twelve", order_count: "1"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_twelve_fourteen", order_count: "0"}
(index):121 {bins: "bin_fourteen_plus", order_count: "0"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format for the second block of code seems to be wrong.You should check out the  API [documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch#csv) for `d3.csv()`.

The following code below should work, assuming the file path is correct.

```
d3.csv('DELTA_7_6_20_10.csv', function(d) {
  return {
    bins: d.bins,
    order_count: Number(d.order_count)
  };
}).then(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: OMG this is the greatest website everrrr! I have been using parseFloat, parseInt, +d. all week and going nuts!!! This entire time it was just Number() Thank you thank you!

Comment: @LMags you are most welcome :) But do take note of the usage of the `Number()` method! If you try to do things like `Number('')`, `Number(null)`, it will return you a `0`. If you try to use `Number()` on a string value such as 'aa', it will return `NaN`. So you might need to do some kinda validation on the to make sure `d.order_count` is a valid number in string format to prevent any unexpected output.